# LAST_ANALYZE null after dbms_stats.gather_table_stats

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-golden-gate

We have a replication with goldengate from a prod environment.
The tables got initial dumped from the prod and afterwards we started the replication with goldengate. Now we want to migrate the data to another database. But the query plans are different from the prod environment. We think it is because all statistics from the database of the replication are broken/wrong.
The number of rows stated in dba_tables are null, 0 or differs 50-80%.
We tried to do `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats` on all relevant tables.
It's still broken. We run that querie for all tables that had wrong statistics:

```sql
dbms_stats.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME => 'SCHEMA', TABNAME => 'TABLE_NAME', CASCADE => true);
```

We can't migrate with the bad queryplans.

We are using Oracle Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production

**EDIT:** After the answer of @Jon Heller we saw that some indices are partitioned in the prod environment not in the replication. Additionally the global preference DEGREE is 32768 on the replication and NULL on prod.

Answer (score 1):

Are the tables built exactly the same way?  Maybe a different table structure is causing the statistics to break, like if one table is partitioned and another is not.  Try comparing the DDL:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'TABLE1') from dual;
```

I'm surprised to hear that statistics are wrong even after gathering stats.  Especially the number of rows - since 10g, that number should always be 100% accurate with the default settings.

Can you list the exact commands you are using to gather stats?  Also, this is a stretch, but possibly the global preference were changed on one database.  It would be pretty evil, but you could set a database default to only look at 0.00001% of the data, which would create terrible statistics.  Check your global preferences between both databases.

```
--Thanks to Tim Hall for this query: https://oracle-base.com/dba/script?category=monitoring&file=statistics_prefs.sql
SELECT DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('AUTOSTATS_TARGET') AS autostats_target,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('CASCADE') AS cascade,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('DEGREE') AS degree,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('ESTIMATE_PERCENT') AS estimate_percent,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('METHOD_OPT') AS method_opt,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('NO_INVALIDATE') AS no_invalidate,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('GRANULARITY') AS granularity,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('PUBLISH') AS publish,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('INCREMENTAL') AS incremental,
       DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('STALE_PERCENT') AS stale_percent
FROM   dual;
```

If gathering statistics still leads to different results, the only thing I can think of is corruption.  It may be time to create an Oracle service request.

(This is more of an extended comment than an answer, but it might take a lot of code to diagnose this problem.  Please update the original question with more information as you find it.)

Comment: I edited my question with new informations from your answer.